# Does async/await execution have a higher priority than setTimeout callbacks?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout

I was writing some code where a user would click a button and the time of the next locally-visible solar eclipse would be computed.

This can be a very time-consuming calculation. So I wrote the calculation code with a couple of nested async functions, breaking all of the computations into bite-size pieces, allowing execution to yield frequently so that the user's web browser wouldn't lock up during the calculation.

Here's a grossly simplified test case of the timing issues involved, without the astronomical complexity [(available on CodePen)](https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/NWzWEYq?editors=1010):

```
window.CP.PenTimer.MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT = 15000;

async function workWorkWork(msg) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const start = performance.now();

    while (performance.now() < start + 5000) {
      await new Promise((innerResolve) => {
        let t = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; ++i) t += Math.sin(Math.random());

        console.log(msg || t);
        // innerResolve(); // What I thought should have been sufficient
        setTimeout(innerResolve); // What I had to do instead
      });
    }

    resolve();
  });
}

let busy = false;

function doStart() {
  if (busy)
    return;

  const button = document.getElementById('my-button');

  button.innerText = 'Started';
  button.style.background = 'red';
  busy = true;

  (async () => {
    setTimeout(() => (button.innerText = 'Busy'), 1000);
    workWorkWork('other work');
    await workWorkWork();
    busy = false;
    button.innerText = 'Start';
    button.style.background = 'unset';
  })();
}
```

After the user clicked the button, I wanted to wait for one second to go by before showing a busy indicator. The busy indicator was activated using a `setTimeout` called just before `await`-ing the calculation.

To my surprise, my the UI responded almost as if the async/await was blocking code. The whole calculation finished after several seconds, and *then* the busy indicator appeared, way too late.

Console output demonstrates that if I start up two calls of `workWorkWork` simultaneously, their output is interleaved in the web console, so each execution instance is properly yielding time to the other.

But the async function code doesn't yield any time to the `setTimeout` that was queued up before the function was called. It doesn't even let the DOM update with changes made before the async call and before the `setTimeout`.

The only way to get the `setTimeout` callback to run in a timely manner appears to be using other `setTimeout` calls within my async functions.

My first encounter with this problem was inside Angular code, and I figured I might be seeing an Angular-specific problem with the Angular Zone.js craziness, but I've now replicated the same problem in plain-ol' JavaScript.

Is this the behavior I should have expected? Is this documented anywhere?

Googling various combinations an permutations of async, await, setTimeout, Promise, etc., yields a lot of material which unfortunately has nothing to do with what I've run into here.

Correct behavior after clicking **Start**:

> Button turns red, text changes to "Started".
> About one second later, text changes to "Busy"
> About four more seconds later, red background disappears and text changes back to "Start".

Bad behavior after clicking **Start**, without extra `setTimeout`:

> Button makes no immediate change of text or color
> About five seconds later, text changes to "Busy", and gets stuck that way.

Comment: Promise resolution is a microtask, timers aren't... (Read up on the event loop and the microtask queue to learn more.)

Comment: I realize that async functions simply return Promises (it's hard to escape noticing that when you're writing in TypeScript and have to declare return types like `Promise<boolean>`), and I even tried a variation of this code using `then()` rather than `await`. Same results, not surprisingly.

Comment: `async`/`await` does not magically make your synchronous code asynchronous. The `for` loop is executed, let's say, "on the foreground" and it takes time to complete (about 350 ms on my computer). The browser is busy running the `for` loop, it does not do anything else until it completes. `setTimeout()` is the only thing that introduces asynchronous behaviour but the "async" activity of the browser in this case is to wait for the timeout to complete. Use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) to run the time consuming calculations in the background.

Comment: @axiac, oh, I wasn't expecting magical asynchronicity. I definitely and effectively had broken the code up so that it could yield time to other code. It was only the issue (which I just learned of from this post) of microtasks having a higher priority than timer tasks that was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fulfilled promises are served via a microtask queue which gets handled BEFORE timer events.  `await` works off promises so it also goes before timer events.

So, if both a timer event and a promise fulfillment are both waiting to run their handlers, then the promise will get served first.

Here's some more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) on the microtask queue or more specifically the `PromiseJobs` queue.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the critical vocabulary I was missing in my Google searches was "microtask". Unfortunately, until now, nothing I had read or done with async/await or Promises invoked the microtask concept specifically.

Comment: @kshetline - Good articles on the overall event loop will usually include a discussion of these microtask queues too, but I can certainly see how it's hard to directly search for if you don't know it exists.